# Generate two buttons div

Tags: php, html, wordpress, arrow-keys

I have this page I'm editing (from a wordpress theme called "lay theme"): http://mtthsstffn.altervista.org/

In this carousel that scrolls images, I need to move the "next" "prev" clickable area slightly outside the images. I think I want to make two invisible divs, left and right, that overlay the image and occupy the center-to-left and center-to-right area of the carousel, with a variable length I can define.

A friend suggested to add this

```
<div id="nav-left" style="
    height: 800px;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    ;
    pointer-events: left;
    cursor: move;
    "></div>
inside <div class="lay-carousel-wrap immediate">
```

I think it can be right, but where can I find the files I need to do it?

I looked around the whole website and couldn't find the HTML with this element, hence I think it's automatically generated with PHP, but I have no idea where to start for this.

Furthermore, I would like to implement arrow-keys navigation for this gallery (left and right). It's about modifying a template, may be a bit tricky?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is more than likely going to require a javascript solution rather than just HTML and some CSS. Chances are the theme uses a carousel library. Can you shed some light on which one that might be?

Comment: there is this carousel yes, a wordpress plugin with some javascript

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `style.css` file inside  `plugins/laytheme-carousel/frontend_assets/css/style.css`  and change `.cursor-left` and `.cursor-right` class css to get expected output

```
.col .lay-carousel.cursor-left .lay-carousel-slide {
  cursor: url("../img/cursor_prev.svg"), w-resize; }

.col .lay-carousel.cursor-right .lay-carousel-slide {
  cursor: url("../img/cursor_next.svg"), e-resize; }
```